# saving Core Data arrays and dictionaries

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

referring to my previous question: [Unique value of object to use in section Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35457371/unique-value-of-object-to-use-in-section-swift)

my problem now is core data. this is code to save data following the previous code to populate section and table:

```
let app = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
let context = app.managedObjectContext
let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Movie", inManagedObjectContext: context)!
let movie = Movie(entity: entity, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)
movie.title = title.text
movie.plot = plot.text
movie.genre = genre.text


context.insertObject(movie)

do {
    try context.save()
} catch {
    print("Could not save movie")
}
```

and fetch data is:

```
let app = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
let context = app.managedObjectContext
let fetchRequest  = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Movie")

do {
    let results = try context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
    self.loadMovie = results as! [Movie]
} catch let err as NSError {
    print(err.debugDescription)
}
```

}
but nothing I receive the error on loadMovie Line..

where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, delete the line

```
context.insertObject(movie)
```

because the object has already been inserted in the `let movie =` line.

To load the movies you need to recreate the data structure using the `insertMovie(movie : Movie)` function.

```
let movies = try context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [Movie]
loadMovie.removeAll()
for movie in movies {
    insertMovie(movie)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the answer of your previous question suggested, the `self.loadMovie` now has type `[String:[Movie]]`, so you should probably try casting `results` as `[String:[Movie]]`.

Try `self.loadMovie = results as! [String:[Movie]]` instead.

Comment: unfortunately using [String:[Movie]] I got this error: 
"Errors thrown from here are not handled because the enclosing catch is not exhaustive" . any suggestions?

Comment: You can add another catch block at the end. This post might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32650050/errors-thrown-from-here-are-not-handled-for-do-catch-in-swift-2-0.